# date_range doesn't include my start and end dates at weekly frequency

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When I put in two dates and set it to weekly frequency I notice that it doesn't include either of the dates in the list.

`pd.date_range(start = '2021-08-30' , end = '2021-11-8' , freq = "W")`

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2021-09-05', '2021-09-12', '2021-09-19', '2021-09-26',
               '2021-10-03', '2021-10-10', '2021-10-17', '2021-10-24',
               '2021-10-31', '2021-11-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-SUN')
```

The only assumption I can use is that the start and end are on the same day of the week but I do not want to use a tag such as `freq = "w-mon"` because I want the code to be independent of the day of the week that my start date is on. It seems freq = "W" defaults to "W-SUN".  Any workarounds?

Comment: try `'7D'` as your `freq`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but this code will give you the date of the nearest Sunday.

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2021-08-30'
end = '2021-11-08'

start_SUN = pd.to_datetime(start) - pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(start).dayofweek, unit='D')

date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_SUN, end=end, freq='W')

print(date_range)
```